# Consultar querys con Timer en c#

Tags: c#

lo que quiero hacer es que en mi interfaz, se actualice el grid con los nuevos datos que hayan sido ingresados en la bd, busque en un usar un timer, la pregunta es, pongo el codigo del query dentro del timer?
en propiedades lo tengo con Enabled=true Interval=6000
para que se actualice cada minuto
mi bd: kitchen, las tablas: 
`agrupado,ingrediente, comboProducto, combo, producto, comanda, kitchenConfig`

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        //Consulta

        timer1.Start();
    }
```

de ante mano gracias.

mi base de datos es MySQL y uso VS 2012

```
 private void DataTableSelectionA()
        {
            DataTable okei = new DataTable("DataTableSelection");
            this.DataTableSelection = new DataTable();
            this.DataTableSelection.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
            this.DataTableSelection.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.DataTableSelection.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));

        }





 private void LoadConfigDataKitchenArea()
        {
            this.DataKitchenArea = new DataTable();
            this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
            this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.DataKitchenArea.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        }

        private void LoadConfigDataTableSection()
        {
            this.DataTableSection = new DataTable();
            this.DataTableSection.Columns.Add("Sel", typeof(bool));
            this.DataTableSection.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            this.DataTableSection.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        }
```

DUDA: como se escribe un query consulta en c#

Comment: Si lo que quieres es actualizar tu grid cada vez que se actualiza la tabla, y si tu base de datos es SQL Server, y es al menos la versión 2005, puedes activar la opción para recibir notificaciones desde el servidor, así te notifica cuando se insertan, eliminan o modifican registros en una tabla específica. Busca información acerca de SqlDependency.

Comment: Eso es interesante, es MySQL y es version 2012, pero quiero que se actualice en automatico en la interfaz

Comment: ¿MySQL 2012? ¿Seguro? ¿No estás confundiendo con SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Por otro lado, edita tu pregunta agregando el código que utilizas para actualizar tus grids. Finalmente, bienvenido a SOes, recuerda revisar:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hasta donde se, MySql no cuenta con la opción de notificaciones, yo solo la he utilizado en Sql Server, versiones 2005 o posteriores.

Comment: Listo, editada con una duda extra, sobre como se escribe un query consulta para traer los datos dentro del timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component

```
private void InitializeTimer()  
{  
    // Call this procedure when the application starts.  
    // Set to 1 second.  
    Timer1.Interval = 1000;  
    Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);  

    // Enable timer.  
    Timer1.Enabled = true;  

    Button1.Text = "Stop";  
    Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);  
}  

private void Timer1_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)     
{  
   // Set the caption to the current time.  
   Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();  
}  

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
  if ( Button1.Text == "Stop" )  
  {  
    Button1.Text = "Start";  
    Timer1.Enabled = false;  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    Button1.Text = "Stop";  
    Timer1.Enabled = true;  
  }  
}
```

Tendrías que colocar tu procedimiento para llenar el grid dentro de este método:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
```

Buena suerte.

Comment: Pedo donde va la consulta a la base de datos? los querys, de donde se refrescara la interfaz (grid)

Comment: basado en el ejemplo: dentro del método Timer1_Tick. Considera que para una mejor respuesta, necesita existir mayor detalles en la pregunta :D

Comment: okay eso es lo que queria saber, gracias

Comment: Pienso poner el query dentro del timer y mi idea es que en automatico (sin botones) ejecute el query cada minuto, tengo las propiedades del timer enabled = true y interval = 6000, estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: en teoría, debería funcionar, recuerda que la programación se aprende a base de ensayo-error, entre más errores, mejor, adquieres más experiencia y evolucionas más rápido. Te sugiero aprender "threads"(hilos) para evitar que tu programa se cuelgue en caso exista una alta cantidad de datos. Ten en cuenta que antes de actualizar los datos, debes limpiar los datos existentes de las Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas las librerias de `devart`

[dotConnect for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/)

Este tiene implementado `MySqlDependency`

[Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html)

con lo cual podrias recibir eventos en tu codigo ante al actualizacion de los datos en la db, sin tener que implementar ningun timer

La documentacion de la libreria comenta:

> Represents a process that periodically polls the server and fires an event if it detects changes in monitored tables.

la unica desventaja que veo es que esta libreria hay que comprarla ya que es licenciada

La referencia se puede agregar por nuget

[Devart.Data.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.MySql/)